# Process is stopped when I use a command in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh

When I use the follow command in shell，the process will be stopped，why？

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"&

[1]+  Stopped                 ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"
```

the result of ps is

```
zh     24495  0.0  0.0 18816 2364 pts/1    T    19:35   0:00 ssh 127.0.0.1 sleep 10
```

Comment: What happens when you run the same command without the `&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it stays like this for way more that 10 sec, it's probably waiting for input. A password, or the known_hosts (yes/no) prompt.

If you keep doing something in this shell and at some point you see it spit out:

```
~$
[1]+  Done                    ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"
```

then I guess you shouldn't worry, it's been running.

**EDIT:**

I think the `-n` option does it:

```
~$ ssh -n 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10" &
[1] 24545
~$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ssh -n 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10" &
~$
[1]+  Done                    ssh -n 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"
```

From the man page:

> ```
>  -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the
>          background.  A common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine.  For example, ssh -n
>          shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be automatically
>          forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put in the background.  (This does not work if ssh
>          needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)
> ```

Comment: Sometimes it will be like this. But when I type this command in shell,and then I enter the “Enter” key， it will be stopped like this

Comment: Just to be really super-duper pedantic about your meaning, you could `nohup ssh -Tn 127.0.0.1 sleep 10 < /dev/null >> /dev/null 2>&1 &`. The `< /dev/null` is redundant, but makes it really clear what you intend. Tossing any potential output prevents SIGTTOU which might also stop your process. The `nohup` bit is just a bonus...

Answer (score 0):

"&" at the end of the command you have executed tells the shell to run this command in the background.  If you execute "fg" command just after executing your command, your command will be brought to foreground.

Also check <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>bg</kbd> command.

Comment: "&" will let this process run in background,but here the process is stopped, not running

Answer (score 0):

Background process , when trying to access the controlling tty for input or output are automatically suspended. The signals are SIGTTIN and SIGTOUT. The default behavior for the process is to stop itself when these signals are received.

Comment: But this process just sleep and does not need input and output

Comment: well .. you can never be sure ... try `ssh -T localhost 'sleep 10'&` and `ssh  localhost 'sleep 10 < /dev/null > /dev/null'&`